# setup domain with random ip addresses

Tags: linux, domain, ip, dns-zone, ns-record

i set up nameservers as follows

```
ns1.domain.com ip1
ns2.domain.com ip1
ns3.domain.com ip2
ns4.domain.com ip2
ns5.domain.com ip3
ns6.domain.com ip3
```

all dns records and PTR records correctly has been set in both domain panel and directadmin dns configuration

i need users to access diffrent ips from list above randomly every time user refresh a page

what should i do?

---

**Edit**:
thanks for all helps and vote downs :)
I found that setting up domain with multiple ip addresses and name servers does not solve my problem anyway
because Apache is on an specific server ip address and i need to somehow install some proxy stuff on server

Comment: You should explain why you think you need that and what you think it will accomplish.

Comment: every users in page sends request with curl and i want users send this request with different Ip addresses

Comment: I've read that several times and I still can't figure out what "sends this request with different ip addresses" means. Do you mean *to* different IP address? Or *from* them? And, whichever, why do you think you need that and what do you think it will accomplish?

Comment: I'm going to make a wild guess and think he's after DNS round robin. In which case googling for that would be a good start, and then returning with a specific question and an actual config.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you should just add multiple A-records for the given domain the clients are accessing. The DNS server will provide a random IP each time a client asks for it.

It is also called round-robin DNS.

Example:

```
www    IN  A      127.0.0.1
www    IN  A      127.0.0.2
www    IN  A      127.0.0.3
www    IN  A      127.0.0.4
```